# How much time does it take for Google to approve my Google Cloud Messaging register request?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm reading through [This tutorial](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/) that's talking about using XMPP connection server to handle cloud messaging on android devices. In the final paragraph, the author says:

> you have to sign up to use the new features like upstream messaging, XMPP or user notifications. After signing up, Google processes your request and some time later comes back with the approval

Now I need this account ASAP, and I've read on the GCM official page that there are engineers from Google that would give a somehow accurate estimate, I'd appreciate some light-shedding on the matter, an approximate time period if possible. Also, how am I going to know that my sign-up has been approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no approval process necessary. Once you create a [Google Developer Project](https://console.developers.google.com) or a [Firebase Project](https://console.firebase.google.com) you will be ready to use XMPP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response